# Showing duration of a song in uilabel or uitextfield

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am developing a music player application. I have picked music files from the ipod library, and is playing them. I'm using AVAudioPlayer for this. What i need now is to show the duration of the song on the top of the view. I got the duration as

```
NSTimeInterval *duration = [musicplayer duration];
```

But i dont know how to use it to display on the view, on uilabel or uitextfield. Or even using any other value.
Pls help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming label is your UILabel, try this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", duration];
```

Or, if you want it in minute:seconds

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d", (int) (x / 60), ((int) x % 60)]
```

String formatting is your friend here.